# не могу получить контент страницы

Tags: curl

```
$link = "https://obmen24.kh.ua/";
function getFile($link) {
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFile($link) {
    $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";
    if( $ch = curl_init() ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        $out = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $out;
}
```